# Como transformar variáveis de um data frame nos índices de uma matriz com o R?

Tags: r, matriz, dataframe

Eu tenho um data frame com uma série de informações e preciso rearranjar ele em uma outra matriz.

O data frame é do tipo:

```
  userID  itemID  rating  
     169      242     3  
     186      302     3   
     22       377     1
```

(a matriz tem 10.000 itens, com o userID variando até 943 e o itemID variando até 1682, com rating de 1-5) o que eu preciso fazer é montar uma matriz que tenha 943 linhas e 1682 colunas, incialmente preenchida com apenas NA, e eu preciso indexar o  "rating" para cada posição, que respeite as informações do data frame.
Nesse caso, na matriz, eu precisaria que o número que fica na posição
[169,242]<- 3, e o que fica na posição [22,377]<- 1

Mas eu não consigo montar por nada um código que faça isso, preciso de ajuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Pode criar uma matriz vazia com número de linhas igual ao valor máximo de `userID` e número de colunas igual ao máximo de `itemID` e usar um *loop* para preencher os valores de acordo com cada linha do seu data.frame:

```
# Dados de exemplo
dados <- data.frame(
  userID = c(4, 6, 2),
  itemID = c(2, 3, 3),
  rating = c(1, 3, 5))

# matriz vazia
matriz <- matrix(nrow = max(dados$userID), ncol = max(dados$itemID))

for (i in seq_len(nrow(dados))) {
  matriz[dados$userID[i], dados$itemID[i]] <- dados$rating[i]
}

matriz
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]   NA   NA   NA
#> [2,]   NA   NA    5
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA
#> [4,]   NA    1   NA
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA
#> [6,]   NA   NA    3
```

Answer (score 1):

A função base `xtabs` resolve o problema em uma linha de código mas primeiro tem de se transformar as colunas `userID` e `itemID` em `"factor"` com os níveis completos.

```
dados$userID <- factor(dados$userID, levels = 1:max(dados$userID))
dados$itemID <- factor(dados$itemID, levels = 1:max(dados$itemID))
xt <- xtabs(rating ~ userID + itemID, dados)
xt
#      itemID
#userID 1 2 3
#     1 0 0 0
#     2 0 0 5
#     3 0 0 0
#     4 0 1 0
#     5 0 0 0
#     6 0 0 3
```

Para ter `NA` onde estão zeros:

```
is.na(xt) <- xt == 0
xt
#      itemID
#userID 1  2  3
#     1        
#     2       5
#     3        
#     4    1   
#     5        
#     6       3
```

O método `print` para a classe `'xtabs'` tem `na.print = ""` por defeito. Se quiser *ver* os `NA`'s (que estão lá) isso deve ser mudado explicitamente.

```
print(xt, na.print = "NA")
#      itemID
#userID  1  2  3
#     1 NA NA NA
#     2 NA NA  5
#     3 NA NA NA
#     4 NA  1 NA
#     5 NA NA NA
#     6 NA NA  3
```

### Dados

Os dados são os da [resposta do Carlos Eduardo Lagosta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/516606/82237).

Answer (score 0):

Vou usar uma adaptação do dado que você citou como exemplo:

```
df <- read.table(
   header=TRUE, 
   text = 
 "userID  itemID  rating  
     2      3     4  
     3      2     1   
     1      1     3")
```

Em seguida utilizo algumas funções do pacote `tidyverse` para transformar esses dados. Os detalhes de cada uma delas encontram-se nos comentários abaixo:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
#primeiro ordeno os dados pelos valores do itemID para, em seguida, transformá-lo em colunas
    arrange(itemID) %>% 
#Segundo, transponho o itemID para as colunas, e preencho as células com as informações dos ratings
    pivot_wider(
    names_from = itemID, 
    values_from = rating) %>%
#Terceiro, ordeno os dados pelo userID
    arrange(userID) %>%
#Quarto, transformo o userID em índice do dataframe;
    column_to_rownames(., var = "userID")
```

Por fim, transformo o dataframe numa matrix:

```
m <- as.matrix(df2)
```

O que gera o seguinte resultado:

```
print(m)

   1  2  3
1  3 NA NA
2 NA NA  4
3 NA  1 NA
```